# config.xml gets overwritten everytime

Tags: ios, cordova

I've started my first phonegap application today. I have a text input and I want the native iOS keyboard to show up when focus()

Well, the documentation says I should open the appname/platforms/ios/appname/config.xml and change

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
```

to

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

which I did. But whenever I try to run it after rebuild the value keeps change back to "true". 
In fact, I can't edit the config.xml at all because after compilation it always gets overwritten with  original contents.

Not sure why making the keyboard to show up is this difficult.

Can anyone help me with this problem please? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now cordova maintains two config files. one at root directory and one specific to platform. if you are using CLI you should not edit platform specific files. these will be replaced when you run build or run command. You should edit root config file. Hope it will help.

Comment: I tried adding <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" /> to the config.xml in the root directory but keyboard still does not show up :( I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Hi TKP, Sorry but I do not have idea for keyboard visibility issue.  I think you should raise a different ques for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. It was something to do with the emulator. I had to toggle keyboard from the menu in order to get it to pop up.